# Serialize Pandas DataFrame to in-memory buffer representation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, feather

What is the fastest way to serialize a DataFrame to an in-memory representation? Based on some research, it seems to be widely acknowledged that the [Apache Feather](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/feather.html) format is the fastest available format by most metrics.

My goal is to get the serialized bytes of a DataFrame - the only issue with Feather is that I would like to avoid the overhead of writing to and loading from disk, and the Feather API seems to only allow File I/O. Is there a different format I should be looking into for this, or is there perhaps a way in Python to "fake" a file, forcing Feather to write to an in-memory buffer instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`pyarrow` provides `BufferOutputStream` for writing into memory instead of files. In constrast to the docstring, `read_feather` and `write_feather` also support reading from memory / writing into a writer interface.

With the following code, you can serialise a DataFrame into memory without going to the filesystem and then directly reconstruct it again.

```py
from pyarrow.feather import read_feather, write_feather
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa

df = pd.DataFrame({"column": [1, 2]})
output_stream = pa.BufferOutputStream()
write_feather(df, output_stream)
df_reconstructed = read_feather(output_stream.getvalue())
```